# WSDL2OBJC for Android?

Tags: android, iphone, wsdl2objc

I have been using Wsdl2Objc to generate proxy's for my web services to use during IPhone dev....it works GREAT!

I now need a version similar to it, that will generate Java code, the same way.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists wsdltoksoap which can be used to interface with the ksoap2 android library.

I have been having problems with the application, however. It is getting a null pointer exception on my particular WSDL, but it has worked for others

http://code.google.com/p/wsdltoksoap/